# SQL concatenation with ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I want to concatenate a variable name into my SQL query for order by such as the following..

I basically don't wan to use dynamic sql and exec and sp_executesql.

DECLARE @Order VARCHAR(1000)
SET @Order = 'CO_ID DESC'
print @Order
select * From contact where co_username= 'sandeepshm' order by @Order+@Order

select * From contact where co_username= 'sandeepshm' order by CO_ID DESC

[image]

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL - variables can be used in (most) places where a *value* can appear. But they cannot be used in places where a *name* (of an object, column, etc) or other token (such as `asc`/`desc`) is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Case statement but not variable
something like this:

```
declare @sortByCO_id bit
declare @sortbyCo_Username bit

select 
*
from contact 
order by 
    case when @sortByCO_id = 1 then CO_Id else NULL end DESC
    ,case when sortbyCo_Username = 1 then Co_Username else NULL end
```

Comment: Excellent, it worked for me, Thank you so much. Learnt a new thing.